# read reg_binary and convert to string with Chinese and English character

Tags: c#, windows, unicode, registry, arrays

I use some tool to read the registry key of a type `REG_BINARY`
so, it is a `byte array`.

First i tried use `Convert.ToChar` and the code following with:

```
foreach (var strWords in bytes) {
 if (strWords> 31)
    descriptionData = descriptionData + Convert.ToChar(strWords);}
```

but only can solve with English word.

So i change other ways to convert it with following :

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
```

Now a problem is these string `mix with Chinese and English word` , and also have some Garbled.

sample convert result:

```
phone_specs.sql\0z2\0\0\0\0\0桰湯彥灳捥\u2e73煳\u2e6c湬kX\t\u0004뻯\0\0\0\0.\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0phone_specs.sql.lnk\0\

建議作法_20151125.zip\0¢6\0\0\0\0\0建議作法_20151125.zip.lnk\0b\t\u0004뻯\0\0\0\0.\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0建議作法_20151125.zip.lnk\0@\0

_j2aiea4l5uc9b6soimmp0_ (2).doc\0ª2\0\0\0\0\0機愲敩㑡㕬捵戹猶楯浭ば ㈨⸩潤\u2e63湬kx\t\u0004뻯\0\0\0\0.\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0_j2aiea4l5uc9b6soimmp0_ (2).doc.lnk\02\0
```

any idea to solve it ?

Comment: Are you sure your raw data are UTF-16 encoded? Also endianness matters. Wrong encoding will produce garbage results. (assuming binary data does not contain any other _formatting_ to handle string arrays and/or other data...)

Comment: i tried few encode like UTF-8, Little Indian, and Default(Big5) . And the Default Big nearly with Unicode, different in word space

Comment: Do you have any hint about format? If it's, for example, a raw dump of a C struct into a binary array then it may contain _garbage_ and it has to be interpreted.

Comment: i have no idea on the format, i'm using C# winforms and using a tool [link] (https://github.com/EricZimmerman/Registry) . It have ValueData(string) and ValueDataRaw(bytes)

Comment: some data have padding property, so it's need to remove the padding or add into it ?

Comment: Yes, _padding_ (I assume it's just a dump of fixed length char arrays) must be ignored (unless zeroed note that _random_ bytes may produce encoding exceptions).

Comment: so how can i remove the padding, cause i get the data through the tools didn't tell me about the padding place. (only give me some, like this [116],[114],[97],[99],[116],[57] or 74-72-61-63-74-39 )

Comment: Forget one second about that tool. REG_BINARY is _free_ blob where application can write whatever it wants. If it simply was a string array they may had used REG_MULTI_SZ, they're not then you may assume they also wrote something else. Now, "padding" may be alignment between struct fields (check for 4/8 bytes alignment of fields you recognize) or just "unused" space on fixed length strings (in this case just trim after first 0 - according to encoding!!!). Really can't say more unless you post binary representation (and also in that case it may require some time to understand what's that...)

Comment: ok, i got it. i'll try for it